# Phoenix render LiveView from a regular template or controller

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-live-view

Let say we have LiveView rendered from a router via `live "/awesome", AwesomeLive.Index, :index`.

Now, in order to render it from a regular template or controller we need to use `live_render/3`.

But that won't work, because: `cannot invoke handle_params/3 on AwesomeLive.Index because it is not mounted nor accessed through the router live/3 macro`

How to refactor `handle_params/3`? Inside is a autogenerated code via `phx.gen.live`

```
  @impl true
  def handle_params(params, _url, socket) do
    {:noreply, apply_action(socket, socket.assigns.live_action, params)}
  end
```

Inside the `params` is `:not_mounted_at_router`

EDIT:

Not having `handle_params/3` appears to break `live_patch/2` or something and throw JavaScript error:

```
phoenix_live_view.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'el' of null
    at e.value (phoenix_live_view.js:1)
    at phoenix_live_view.js:1
    at e.value (phoenix_live_view.js:1)
    at e.value (phoenix_live_view.js:1)
    at e.value (phoenix_live_view.js:1)
    at phoenix_live_view.js:1
    at phoenix_live_view.js:1
    at Object.callback (phoenix_live_view.js:1)
    at e.value (phoenix.js:1)
    at phoenix.js:1
```

Versions:

- Erlang/OTP 23
- Elixir 1.10.3
- :phoenix, "1.5.1"
- :phoenix_live_view,
  "0.12.1"

Comment: what version of liveview you are using?

Comment: @Daniel I've added versions.

Comment: There are a lot of breaking changes in versions, I can confirm that you can render a liveview from a normal template in version 0.10 .